# text is recognized when i click the picture very closely. it is not even recognizing the text on a business card

Tags: java, android, google-vision

I am using google vision API to get the text that is written in a business card but when I click the picture it only recognizes text that is written in a bigger text or I need to take the picture very closely. then it only recognizes. But I need to focus on a phone no or name or address I couldn't get the whole text that is written on a card together.

And instead if I set the picture in an imageView manually that is not captured but in a good resolution then it recognizes perfect. Is this issue is related to resolution? If anyone having a perfect code for this can you send it?

here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView imgPic;
    TextView tvText;
    Button btnClick, btnCapture;
    private int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgPic = findViewById(R.id.img_pic);
        tvText = findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        btnClick = findViewById(R.id.btn_click);
        btnCapture = findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }


            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imgPic.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


            TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
            if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "could not get the text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(imageBitmap).build();
                SparseArray<TextBlock> items = textRecognizer.detect(frame);
                int size = items.size();
                Log.e("size", String.valueOf(size));
                //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    TextBlock myItem = items.valueAt(i);
                    Log.e("hello", myItem.getValue());
                    sb.append(myItem.getValue());
                    sb.append("\n");


                }

                tvText.setText(sb.toString());


            }


        }

    }


}
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">-->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="capture"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="25sp"
       />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use photo capture like this. According to documentation - **extras.get("data")** contains small preview and should not be used for other purposes then showing preview. You should use camera the other way. There is a Kotlin sample from my library. It creates file in DCIM dir and pass to Camera it's URI to use as output:

```
private fun takePhoto() {
    val photoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    val dirDCIM = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
    val storageDir = File(dirDCIM, "/${config.cameraFolderName}/")
    if (!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()

    currentCameraImageFile = File(storageDir, "photo_${UUID.randomUUID()}.jpg")
    val uri =
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "$packageName.fileprovider", currentCameraImageFile!!)
    photoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)

    val resolvedIntentActivities =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(photoIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
    for (resolvedIntentInfo in resolvedIntentActivities) {
        val packageName = resolvedIntentInfo.activityInfo.packageName
        grantUriPermission(
            packageName,
            uri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        )
    }

    startActivityForResult(photoIntent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

And then check if capture was OK in onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            val photoFile = currentCameraImageFile ?: return
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && photoFile.exists()) {
                // Do your stuff
            } else {
                // If result is not successful - delete temporary photo file
                photoFile.delete()
            }
            currentCameraImageFile = null
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forget to add provider code from "application" section of manifest:

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/imagepicker_file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

And imagepicker_file_paths.xml for provider (stored in resources in xml directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path
    name="imagepicker_images"
    path="." />
</paths>
```